# Knockout.js Change form value based on another form value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, knockout.js

Hi I have a form that contains a yes/no radio button group and another group with about 3 radio button values.

I'm trying to achieve a dynamic where if the value of the first question is 'no' it will select a specific radio button in the second group and disable the user from changing the value. If the user selects 'Yes' they can then pick any option they want from the second group.

I have the disable on condition functionality working correctly but I am struggling to get the functionality to select the '0' radio button in the second group if the 'No' option is selected in the first

My code is:

```
this.isEligibleStateBenefitCd = ko.observable(args.isEligibleStateBenefitCd);
this.weeklyPrsiContributionsRate = ko.computed(args.weeklyPrsiContributionsRate);
```

HTML:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="radio-group" typeof="select_box">
<input data-bind="checked: isEligibleStateBenefitCd" value="Y" type="radio" name="isEligibleStateBenefitCd"/> Yes
<input data-bind="checked: isEligibleStateBenefitCd" value="N" type="radio" name="isEligibleStateBenefitCd"/> No
</div>

<div tabindex="0" class="radio-group" typeof="select_box" data-bind="enable: isEligibleStateBenefitCd() === 'Y'">
<input data-bind="checked: weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" value="238.30" type="radio" name="weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" id="48"> 48 or Over
<input data-bind="checked: weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" value="233.60" type="radio" name="weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" id="4047"> 40-47
<input data-bind="checked: weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" value="0" type="radio" name="weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" id="0"> N/A - €0
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use **subscribe**.

> The subscribe function accepts three parameters: callback is the
>   function that is called whenever the notification happens, target
>   (optional) defines the value of this in the callback function, and
>   event (optional; default is "change") is the name of the event to
>   receive notification for.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

It will trigger every time your isEligibleStateBenefitCd change.

```
self.isEligibleStateBenefitCd.subscribe(function(newValue) {
   if(newValue == 'N'){
      self.weeklyPrsiContributionsRate('0');
   }
});
```

For disable dont use it on div, try it:

```
<input data-bind="checked: weeklyPrsiContributionsRate,enable: isEligibleStateBenefitCd() === 'Y'" value="238.30" type="radio" name="weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" id="48"> 48 or Over

<input data-bind="checked: weeklyPrsiContributionsRate,enable: isEligibleStateBenefitCd() === 'Y'" value="233.60" type="radio" name="weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" id="4047"> 40-47

<input data-bind="checked: weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" value="0" type="radio" name="weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" id="0"> N/A - €0
```

Working example:

```js
$(function(){

  function ViewModal(opt_data) {
    var data = opt_data || {};

    self.isEligibleStateBenefitCd = ko.observable(data.isEligibleStateBenefitCd || 'N');
    self.weeklyPrsiContributionsRate = ko.observable();
    
    self.isEligibleStateBenefitCd.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        if(newValue == 'N'){
         self.weeklyPrsiContributionsRate('0');
          
        }
    });
    
  }

  var data = {
    "isEligibleStateBenefitCd": 'Y'
  };
  
  var vm = new ViewModal(data);
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div tabindex="0" class="radio-group" typeof="select_box">
<input data-bind="checked: isEligibleStateBenefitCd" value="Y" type="radio" name="isEligibleStateBenefitCd"/> Yes
<input data-bind="checked: isEligibleStateBenefitCd" value="N" type="radio" name="isEligibleStateBenefitCd"/> No
</div>

<div tabindex="0" class="radio-group" typeof="select_box">

<input data-bind="checked: weeklyPrsiContributionsRate,enable: isEligibleStateBenefitCd() === 'Y'" value="238.30" type="radio" name="weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" id="48"> 48 or Over

<input data-bind="checked: weeklyPrsiContributionsRate,enable: isEligibleStateBenefitCd() === 'Y'" value="233.60" type="radio" name="weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" id="4047"> 40-47

<input data-bind="checked: weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" value="0" type="radio" name="weeklyPrsiContributionsRate" id="0"> N/A - €0

</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks! The reason why I had the div disabled was because my actual code has the inputs hidden and are selected via labels. I took this out to simplify the code.